# ссылки в тексте

Tags: javascript, html, css

вопрос: как сделать ссылку в тексте, так чтобы шел параграф единым целым (текст текст ссылка текст), как в википедии, например.

> Линкоры получили мощную батарею из двадцати 127-мм орудий (ссылка). В
>   годы войны неудачные 28-мм зенитные автоматы  (ссылка) были заменены
>   на 40-мм «Бофорсы» и 20-мм «Эрликоны». На Тихом океане основной
>   ударной силой становились авианосцы  (ссылка).

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так сделать

```
Текст до ссылки <a href="Ссылка">Текст ссылки</a> Текст после ссылки
```

Кроме html тут ни чего не надо.

Comment: значит, я в CSS до этого натворила, вот у меня и все разъехалось по разным углам((( спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вот такое [решение](https://github.com/bryanwoods/autolink-js) сойдет? Перебивает открытые ссылки в теги.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Ок понял. Чтобы не перебивать ссылки каждый раз вручную проще просто указывать ссылки в редакторе после чего скрипт по выше указанной ссылке будет автоматически переделывать их в текст с ссылкой. Это проще чем каждый раз прописывать теги. При желании можно еще функцию на js накидать чтобы полностью автоматизировать данное решение (избавиться от autolink()).